# How to avoid Excel recalculate all when a different excel workbook is udpated?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've some excel workbooks (files) always opened.
These files are full of formulas.
I would like to avoid that if i update a workbook formula , all others workbook are re-updated.

Is it possibile to avoid this behaviour ?

Thanks

Comment: The setting for Manual or Automatic recalculation is universal. So all you can do is set to Manual and recalculate when you wish to . This is prone to error if multiple sheets are involved,

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off automatic recalculation by go to the Calculation options section and click Manual.